# How do I open an HTML file with CSS events enabled on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I am emailing users a report in html format.  The html file has CSS events (e.g. hover and active) to highlight or change visibility of some rows.  No javascript.

When I run this in a browser the CSS works fine, but when i open the html attachment in the iOS "Mail" app the CSS events do not work.

Is there any way to open an html file on iOS with CSS enabled?

Comment: how are you doing the css? inline via `<style...>` blocks, or as external `<style src=....`?

Comment: Are they inside the html or in a separate stylesheet file? Mail clients tend to be quite strict on how styles work.
You can try adding them inline or embedded into your html.

Comment: they are inside the html, like <head> <style>...</style> <body>...<body></html>

Comment: Try adding them inline... Ran into a similar situation a few months ago with gmail which doesn't accept styles other than inline

Comment: Most email apps is very restricted when it comes to events, and since you can't run css `:hover` inline and script normally won't work, you are likely not being able to accomplish what you want

Comment: Have you tried put the `style` inside the `body`? ... Most email apps delete the html `head` element and the `style` with it

Comment: Most mail readers ignore `<style>` blocks in HTML email. You can only define styles in `style=` attributes on the elements, and there's no way to do that for pseudo-elements like `:hover` and `:active`.

Comment: How are you opening the attachment? If you open it in Safari, it should process the HTML and CSS just like on a desktop.

Comment: @Barmar i would like to open in safari but mail doesn't give me the option

Comment: What application does it use to open the attachments instead of Safari? Is it showing the HTML inline instead of as an attachment? Are you sure you sent it as an attachment, not as an HTML message body?

Comment: @Barmar mail opens the html attachment within the mail app itself.  there's no option to open in safari or chrome.

Comment: See http://email.about.com/od/iphonemailtips/qt/How-To-Open-Attachments-In-External-Apps-From-Iphone-Mail.htm it says you should be able to press on the attachment icon until an "Open With" menu comes up, then you can select an app to open it with.

Answer (score 0):

Use Webkit in your styles like this

```
    transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(10px);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(10px); 
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(10px);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(10px);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1) skew(1deg) translate(10px);
```

Comment: I believe the question is not about browser compatibily but making the styles work